Rabbitmq Configuration
I have deleted and recreated the rabbitmq queue with the version 2 properties But I am getting this error
12:57:55.286 [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory  - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'cats.inventory.rack.healt.error' in vhost '/': received 'DLX' but current is 'DLC', class-id=50, method-id=10)
12:57:55.356 [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory  - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'cats.inventory.rack.health.testing' in vhost '/': received 'DLX' but the current is 'DLC', class-id=50, method-id=10)

I deleted all the queues and restarted the rabbitmq but got the
How to update the property from classic to quorum

Post some of your code, maybe you configure dead letter queue name as 'DLC' but by default it is 'DLX'.
